# Set the top 11 players on a list according to highest percentages (Google Sheets)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

The list of players (`COLUMN D`) is ranked from most important to least important, but I want to list the 11 players who participated most in the last three matches.

If the top 11 had the same percentage, I could use the `MAX` function as I tried to do. But the percentages are not equal.

[image]

What I would need was to create a way to find the highest percentages until he found 11 players.

One problem is that when trying to find lower percentages, it lists more than 11 if they have more players with the same percentage.

For example: If happen to complete the list of 11 players need to define between two that have 50%, the chosen one must be the highest one in `COLUMN D`

I thought of `FILTER + LEN` to get to `11`, but couldn't find a pattern for finding the lowest percentages and the highest rating in `COLUMN D` as a tiebreaker.

Below the spreadsheet link for ease of understanding:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fh2todBAFApGNyKw3f30p3pAAD3DHOVv6qqymHPxLyo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
=QUERY(D4:H, "select D order by H desc limit 11", 0)
```